# Meaning of phrase "constructors do not have names" in the C++ Standard

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, c++14

While trying to understand the phrase "constructors do not have names" in the C++ Standard, it seems like I found an error in clang. Could someone confirm this?

<s>`VS2015`</s> <s>and</s> `gcc` rejects this code, and I think <s>they</s> it <s>are</s> is correct. At least, this is the impression I get from §12.1[class.ctor]/2 in N4140:

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  A::A();
}
```

**§12.1[class.ctor]/2** in N4140:

> A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type. Because
>   constructors do not have names, they are never found during name
>   lookup; ...

With the expression `A::A();` above, clang finds the constructor by name lookup, when it should find the type name `A` instead. See [live example](http://rextester.com/SMAQ78852).

Comment: Your code compiles just fine with MSVC on the site you linked to. GCC is the odd one out.

Comment: Clang has a number of known bugs in its handling of injected-class-names. Anyway, since this context doesn't ignore function names, `A::A` names the constructor and is ill-formed by [\[class.qual\]/p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.qual#2)

Comment: @SebastianRedl VS2015 does not compile the code either

Comment: @Belloc As I just said, according to the page you linked to for Clang, it does: http://rextester.com/ZNL92764 - Does your local installation behave differently?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'm talking about VS2015 installed on my computer. Maybe rextester isn't using this compiler yet.

Comment: @T.C. But is it correct to say that the lookup for the second `A` in the expression `A::A();` should find the type `A` and not the constructor `A()` according to §12.1/2? That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: The only `A` it can find is the type, because the constructor doesn't have a name. Then per [class.qual]/2, the name is considered to name the constructor instead, but clang doesn't implement this part.

Comment: @T.C. I don't understand when you say `clang doesn't implement this part`. clang is invoking the constructor.

Comment: @T.C. It seems to me [class.qual]/2 doesn't apply here, as function names are ignored in this case. Aren't they?

Comment: @Belloc: It doesn't implement this part, because calling the constructor is illegal, so the program would error out. Instead, it's falling back on the only other way to interpret the statement, which is as construction of a temporary of type `A` (which, of course, invokes the constructor anyway).

Comment: @SebastianRedl You were right. `VS2015` and `clang` accept the code. `gcc` rejects it. (see my edit above).

Comment: @Belloc It's not ignored. In a lookup that ignores function names, you can name a type even if it would otherwise be hidden by a function of the same name (e.g., the infamous `stat` in `struct stat`).

Comment: @T.C. Yes, I have to agree, functions names are not ignored in this case. Than, I must conclude what you`re saying is that clang and VS2015 are correct and gcc is wrong. Is that correct?

Comment: How did you manage to get the complete opposite of what I've been saying?

Comment: @T.C. As function names are not ignored, by [class.qual]/2 the second `A` in the expression `A::A();` in the code, names a constructor for class `A`. And this shows that vs2015 and clang are correct.

Comment: No, because [class.qual]/2 also says "Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration."

Comment: @T.C. You 're right, I missed that. Just one more question: using the Standard, how do I justify that the constructor is invoked in the following case: `#include <iostream> struct A{ A() {std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; } }; int main() { A(); }`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2

Comment: @T.C. I would have never found this by myself. Many thanks. FWIW, I consider you one of the most knowledgeable guys in C++, that I've met so far. Thanks again.

Comment: The part "they are never found during name lookup" in the spec is not correct. It should be corrected.

Comment: @T.C. You cited [expr.type.conv]/2 to justify the expression `A();` in the snippet `struct A{}; int main() { A(); }`. But [expr.type.conv]/2 mentions a *simple-type-specifier* and the definition of a *simple-type-specifier* has an optional `nested-name-specifier`. Then, why can't I say that the expression `A::A();` in `int main() { A::A(); }` is also well-formed?

Comment: Because *`A::A` is taken to name the constructor and not the type*?

Comment: @T.C. This is really complicated. Let me see if I understood it correctly: `A::A` names a constructor because function names are not ignored in this case, even though a constructor cannot be used in this situation, because the expression `A::A();` would not be a *declarator-id* of a declaration that names a constructor. Is that the idea?

Comment: @Belloc Either that, or it's parsed as an equally-ill-formed ([class.mfct]/2) redeclaration of the constructor.

Comment: @T.C. I think I've got it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @T.C. In your comment about the "infamous `stat` in `struct stat`" [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842988/meaning-of-phrase-constructors-do-not-have-names-in-the-c-standard#comment55463154_33842988), were you referring to [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.name#2)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. This is a known Clang bug [13403](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13403) with status `NEW`.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that this should not compile.

It's actually more bizzare than you thought. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A() {
        std::cout << "A() " << this << '\n';
    }

    void foo() {
        std::cout << _message << std::endl;
    }

    std::string _message = "hello";
};

int main()
{
    A::A().foo();
}
```

example output:

```
A() 0x7fff5cd105f8
hello
```

It looks to me as if an un-named A is being implicitly created.

Comment: Huh? How did "hello" get printed?

Comment: `_message` is intitialised to "hello" in the constructor. `foo()` prints `_message`.