# Trying to understand [class.qual]/2 in the C++ Standard

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, c++14

According to the answers I obtained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33842988/1042389), the code below is ill-formed, notwithstanding the fact that `clang` and `vs2015` accept it.

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
public:
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  A::A();
}
```

Nevertheless the code below appears to work in all 3 compilers (see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cf42b75b19560ca)). AFAICT, according to [class.qual/2] the code is ill-formed. Or am I missing something here?

```
#include <iostream>
struct B { B() { std::cout << "B()" << '\n'; } };
struct A : public B { };
int main()
{
    A::B();
}
```

Also, according to [class.qual]/2, the code below is well-formed and in this case, all 3 compilers produce the expected output (see example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fa3ba388d154ddc)).

```
include <iostream>
struct B { B() { std::cout << "B()" << '\n'; } };
struct A : public B { using B::B; A() { std::cout << "A()" << '\n'; }  void f() { B(); } };
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();
}
```

Output:

```
B()
A()
B()
```

But I'd like to know what is the usefulness of a *using-declaration* naming a constructor, as the one (`using B::B;`) in class `A` above. Note that this *using-declaration* is totally irrelevant in this case, no matter whether `B` is a base class of `A`, or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the your second sample is well-formed. The rule in `[class.qual]/2` states that the name refers to the constructor if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier* when looked up in `C` is the injected-class-name of `C`. In the case of `A::B`, the name specified after the nested-name-specifier is the injected-class-name of `B` (visible due to inheritance), not `A`. In this case, `A::B` unambiguously names a type, `A::B()` creates a temporary `B` instance.

Using-declarations naming constructors can be useful to promote base-class constructors which take arguments:

```
struct B { B(int a) { std::cout << "B " << a << '\n'; } };
struct A : public B { using B::B; };
int main()
{
    A a{1}; //would not be valid without the using-declaration
}
```

Comment: Your example above seems to confirm what you're saying. But could you provide a quote from the Standard supporting this construction. I've never seen this construction before.

Comment: The standardese is a bit long for sticking it in my question, but you'll probably want to look at `[class.inhctor]`

Comment: After a quick look into [class.inhctor] I have to agree with you. It seems to answer my second question (+1). But I'm still not convinced about my first question.

Comment: In the example in [class.qual]/2 the declaration `B::A ba; // object of type A` seems to contradict what you said above, in relation to my first question.

Comment: @Belloc what does it contradict? `B::A();` declares a function, `B::A ba;` creates an automatic variable called `ba` of type `A`.

Comment: This belongs to [class.qual]/2: `Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration.`

Comment: @Belloc but that's not a constructor name. It names the type. `B::B` and `A::A` name constructors, `B::A` names a type.

Comment: `A::B();` is not a **declaration** naming a constructor. If correct, It would be an expression invoking the `B` constructor, but not a declaration. See my discussion with T.C. in the comments to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33842988/1042389.

Comment: @Belloc That discussion is about `A::A()`, which is completely different from `B::A()`. The former can name a constructor under `[class.qual]/2` but will `be used only in the declarator-id etc.`, but the latter does *not* name a constructor, so that rule does not apply.

Comment: `A::B();` declares nothing. It's an expression-statement.